# Is there an alternative to nuclear reactors for high-power spacecraft?

Tags: propulsion, technology, power, natural-resources, nuclear

Many of my favorite ideas for space exploration, such as large outer solar system probes, or the Mars Direct human Mars exploration proposal, require nuclear reactors to supply the high-power requirements of the spacecraft. However I have never very much liked the idea of a large amount of refined uranium being put on top of a possible bomb (the rocket fuel). I am specifically concerned the possibility of the rocket exploding, sending radioactive uranium around the globe in a mini-Chernobyl.

Assuming we will not be getting fusion reactors anytime soon, what alternatives are there to nuclear fission power where solar power is not enough for a mission. Also, since there needs to be a high-power source on the surface of a planet (Mars) for Mars Direct, what high-power sources could be used on a planet such as Mars?

Comment: Uranium-235 when the reactor has not worked at all is rather harmless. So, your fears of a launch accident are, quoting Mark Twain, slightly exaggerated.

Comment: Spacecraft have limited solar array size because of launch mass, but once you have the equipment on Mars to manufacture solar panels, potential power is unlimited.

Comment: RTGs are not fission.  A large number of PV panels would be fine on Mars (if you could make/getthem there), but OPalso mentions "outer solar system". (I know you know, just tossing it in there.)

Comment: Hydrothermal, geothermal. Locomotive generation through magnetic fields (Jup, Sat).

Comment: @hunter2 - I wish us all good luck finding hydrothermal sources on Mars (seriously).

Comment: @DeerHunter "OP also mentions *"outer solar system"*"   Europa, at least.   Sure, Mars would be nice, too.

Comment: As gently noted by @DeerHunter, your premise of refined Uranium being dangerously radioactive is false.  There may be reasons to consider alternatives, but the launch of radioactive material is not one of them.  Good reasons are cost and schedule.  It costs a lot to develop, build, and test a new nuclear system, and it takes a long time.

Comment: @TheHighFrontier In one cubic kilometer of sea water, there is 3.3 **tons** of uranium. Are you really worried that a satellite using about... say, 0.1 tons of uranium might plonk down in the Atlantic with its 300+ **million** cubic kilometers of water?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is really a wrap-up of comments from Deer Hunter, Gerrit and Hunter2:

Your options include:

- Solar Power: effective when close to the sun. Beyond Mars' orbit this becomes less useful for power generation
- RTG - Radioisotope Thermoelectric Generator: this is used for long missions, and it really isn't very dangerous. These are not fission reactors - they simply generate relatively small amounts of heat through radioactive decay.
- Hydrothermal - would work on a body with sufficient liquid with a decent temperature differential (Europa?)
- Geothermal - would work on a geologically active body (Io?)
- Magnetic- Jupiter and Saturn have strong magnetic fields which may be usable. Between Io and Jupiter there is a plasma torus, which may also be a source of energy

Additionally, we have a few related questions:

- [What power source options provide reliable and sustainable power generation for a Martian Colony](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/301/38)
- [Are there any safe-to-launch alternatives to RTG's for outer solar system exploration?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17/38)
- [How far from the Sun can solar power be used as a reliable energy source?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/623/38)
- [What types of sustainable energy are available beyond Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1193/49)

Comment: Where's "chemical" - for high power (as in force) chemical rockets are still the main way to go. RTG's are typically not high power.

Comment: Chemical is just not long term - you have to carry too much. High Power /=  sustainable.

Comment: The question did however not include sustainability. And for missions to mars chemical rockets are a viable choice.