# Was the telltale on the Mars Phoenix Lander used for meteorology? Why not a hot wire anemometer instead?

Tags: mars, weather

Reading about [ping pong ball anemometers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemometer#Ping-pong_ball_anemometers) I discovered that the [Mars Phoenix Lander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_(spacecraft)#Meteorological_station) had an anemometer of this design, and there are images and GIFs of it moving. When imaged from one or two different angles, it gives an estimate of wind velocity and direction. But imaging is a lot of bandwidth and memory (especially back then).

There was also a LIDAR instrument, but I don't know how demanding it was for power, or bandwidth, and if it could be pointed in at least a few directions fast enough to establish the direction of the wind, nor do I know if the direction was important.

After reading Wikipedia's article on [Phoenix's Meteorological station](http://marslab.au.dk/) I get the idea that they were looking for times when the wind was minimal, so that they could do sample loading without losing the smallest particles due to wind.

Wouldn't a [hot-wire anemometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemometer#Hot-wire_anemometers) have used much less bandwidth and been easier to read? I think that as long as the air temperature is measured approximately, and certainly the pressure would be available from the weather station, this should work fine.

Also this looks a bit on the heavy side for a payload to Mars, compared to a hot wire, but that's just my perception.

[image: GIF from images transmitted from Mars of the telltale on the Phoenix Mars Lander]

**above:** GIF from images transmitted from Mars. From the [The Telltale project](http://marslab.au.dk/research/instrument-development/the-telltale-project/) page on the [Mars Simulation Laboratory](http://marslab.au.dk/). Also [archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120220080017/http://www.marslab.dk/TelltaleProject.html).

[image]

**above:** Instrument as delivered to NASA. From the [The Telltale project](http://marslab.au.dk/research/instrument-development/the-telltale-project/) page on the [Mars Simulation Laboratory](http://marslab.au.dk/). Also [archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120220080017/http://www.marslab.dk/TelltaleProject.html). That's a 45 degree mirror below the telltale providing a simultaneous view from below.

Comment: I suspect hot-wire anemometers don't work very well at the very low pressure of mars atmosphere.

Comment: Not to mention low density atmosphere that is predominantly CO2. Calibrating a hot wire anemometer for such conditions would have taken some effort. Looking at the 2D movements of a dangling objects would be simpler.

Comment: @Uwe Why do you think so? Rate of collisional heat loss would scale with rate of collisions ($\sim \rho v$ or $\sim \rho \sqrt{T_{atm}}$) while rate of radiative heat loss would scale as $\sim T_{wire}^4$ so as long as the temperature were not so high that radiative cooling was dominant, I'm thinking that it should be a straightforward, stable, calibrated correction. If I'm wrong, then that would be the basis of a good answer! However I do need to adjust the question wording, since *there is* a $T_{atm}$ dependence.

Comment: @Fred I don't understand. Why would that be hard? NASA has bottles of CO2 and pumps and gauges and MFCs, this could be done in an undergraduate physics lab. There is an entire [weather station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_(spacecraft)#Meteorological_station) (linked above) that has been calibrated for Mars already for goodness sake! Recording, buffering and later transmitting a new image for every velocity measurement *is not easier* than recording, buffering, and later transmitting single voltage readings. There is a difference in weight also. In fact, I see nothing that is simpler.

Comment: @Fred Also, what is it about the "ping pong ball" anemometer shown that would not *also require calibration for the atmosphere of Mars* as well? While the surface gravity is known, the aerodynamic force on the telltale would need characterization. Further, flexing shown in the GIF is not even happening at a fixed point, so the mechanics of the bending would also need to be calibrated *in the substantially reduced gravity field of Mars!!* I would not call that easy two decades ago.

Comment: A paper about using hot-wire anemometers at low pressure: http://enu.kz/repository/2011/AIAA-2011-1166.pdf read bottom of page 2.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia page, hot wire anemometers are fragile, using wire thickness on the order of micrometers. That might make it difficult to make one robust enough to survive launch and landing.

Comment: @Hobbes: the dust of the martian atmosphere may be an additional problem when using very thin hot wires for anemometry.

Comment: @Uwe great paper, thanks! It seems they are focusing on turbulence measurements in wind tunnels, thus the terminology. Here we need to look at devices designed specifically for low velocity measurements. But the math and technical issues discussed there are helpful and I'll keep reading.